# How to keep content type as png instead of x-png after image resizing with imageresizer.dll

Tags: c#, html, web-applications, imageresizer

I am using image resizing in my C#  application to resize png images(imageresizer.dll at http://imageresizing.net/). 
I noticed that when png images are resized they are converted to to x-png
If I go straight to an image without resizing then examine the header Content-Type: = image/png (This is correct type)
{server host}/Content/VevoImages/video/2109BE0486B5D47906280AB28F36FE2D.png
After adding resizing string to the above URL the image is resized but the Content type changes.. Content-Type: = image/x-png
{server host}/Content/VevoImages/video/2109BE0486B5D47906280AB28F36FE2D.png?width=156&height=88&crop=auto

How can I force image resize to maintain the same content type after image resizing … Content-Type: = image/png?

Comment: Please remember to specify which Version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version. In current version, `/Core/Plugins/Basic/DefaultEncoder.cs:`

```
if (ImageFormat.Png.Equals(format)) 
    return "image/png"; //Changed from image/x-png to image/png on May 14, 2011, per http://www.w3.org/Graphics/PNG/
```

Comment: Where exactly in the current version would I find this?

Comment: I can seem to find this anywhere in the ImageResizer.dll

Comment: I was using .netreflector to look at the classes and methods in the imageresizer.dll to verify that the old code returned image/x-png. The problem is I added the latest imageresizer.dll and I am now getting a ton of errors.

Comment: @user1526912 it should be `ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder.GetContentTypeFromImageFormat`, can you find it?

Comment: Could not load type 'fbs.ImageResizer.InterceptModule'. at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement,

Answer (score 0):

### You are using a very old version of ImageResizer, likely V2.1 (2010)

For a backwards-compatible upgrade, you can switch to V2.8: http://imageresizing.net/releases/2-8

However, note that V2.8 was end-of-lifed july 2011, and has unpatched memory leaks (small ones, however).

Upgrading to V3 [requires a few steps](http://imageresizing.net/docs/2to3/guide), but is much faster and much more reliable. You'll only have to change a few strings in web.config.